# "Webhook is already deleted" вместо "Webhook was set"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, flask

Создаю своего первого бота в Телеграм и столкнулся с проблемой. Мне надо передать публичный адрес Телеграму с помощью консоли, но когда я пишу в ней `curl --location --request POST "https://api.telegram.org/botМОЙ_ТОКЕН_БОТА/setWebhook" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{"url": "МОЙ_АДРЕС_СЕРВЕРА"}"` в ответ получаю вместо `{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}` `{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already deleted"}`

В чём моя проблема? Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу найти решение.

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно передаёте `--data-row`. Вместо:

```
--data-raw "{"url": "МОЙ_АДРЕС_СЕРВЕРА"}"
```

Правильно:

```
--data-raw '{"url": "МОЙ_АДРЕС_СЕРВЕРА"}'
```

Полный запрос:

```sh
curl --location --request POST "https://api.telegram.org/botМОЙ_ТОКЕН_БОТА/setWebhook" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{"url": "МОЙ_АДРЕС_СЕРВЕРА"}'
```

Comment: Тогда помимо вышеперечисленного выдаёт ещё ```curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 30```

Comment: Как Вы отправляете? Смотрите внимательнее, где-то Вы забыли закрыающую фигурную скобку

Comment: Вроде бы всё нормально, несколько раз перепроверил. Вот полный запрос ```curl --location --request POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot1800198302:AAGu4ZBLh_tSNnI8XLiF7eRN3TsMjuj3NdY/setWebhook" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{"url": "https://a2a0ab0ab387.ngrok.io"}'```

А вот ответ ```{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already deleted"}curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 30```

Comment: Не знаю, как Вы команду используете, я скопировал и запустил у себя, ответ: `{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}`

Answer (score 0):

приветствую всех уважаемые! у меня была аналогичная трабла... много чего перерыл и наткнулся на каком то ресурсе на ответ от "MyZik" - (в setWebhook не передавать тело кода...), должно быть setWebhook?url='url с ngrokа'.
полный запрос выглядит так (использую пример Konstantin):

curl --location --request POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot1800198302:AAGu4ZBLh_tSNnI8XLiF7eRN3TsMjuj3NdY/setWebhook?url=https://a2a0ab0ab387.ngrok.io" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{"url": "https://a2a0ab0ab387.ngrok.io"}'

у меня все заработало. респект MyZik!

Answer (score -1):

Я поменял двойные кавычки на одинарные, теперь у меня эта проблема в Винде
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already deleted"}curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 37:
https://Сервак}'

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).